# How to use R to read XML data from S3 more quickly?

Tags: r, xml, performance, loops, amazon-s3

this is my first time working with XML data, and I'd appreciate any help/advice that you can offer!

I'm working on pulling some data that is stored on AWS in a collection of XML files. I have an index files that contains a list of the ~200,000 URLs where the XML files are hosted. I'm currently using the XML package in R to loop through each URL and pull the data from the node that I'm interested in. This is working fine, but with so many URLs, this loop takes around 12 hours to finish.

Here's a simplified version of my code. The `index` file contains the list of URLs. The parsed XML files aren't very large (stored as `dat` in this example...R tells me they're 432 bytes). I've put `NodeOfInterest` in as a placeholder for the spot where I'd normally list the XML tag that I'd like to pull data from.

```
for (i in 1:200000) {
  url <- paste('http://s3.amazonaws.com/',index[i,9],'_public.xml', sep="")  ## create URL based off of index file
  dat <- (xmlTreeParse(url, useInternal = TRUE))  ## load entire XML file
  nodes <- (getNodeSet(dat, "//x:NodeOfInterest", "x"))  ##find node for the tag I'm interested in

  if (length(nodes) > 0 & exists("dat")) {
      dat2 <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes)  ##create data table from node
      compiled_data <- rbind(compiled_data, dat2)  ##create master file
      rm(dat2)
      }
  print(i)
}
```

It seems like there must be a more efficient way to pull this data. I think the longest step (by far) is loading the XML into memory, but I haven't found anything out there that suggests another option. Any advice???

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you benchmarked or profiled the code? i.e. Did you see where R is spending most of it's time? Is the space for `compiled_data` preallocated? Back of the napkin computation says you're taking 0.216 seconds / file (which is gd given internet latency, XML parsing and the `rbind`ing). One of your options is to use  one of the parallel packages in R to divide & conquer the list. Another is to save the `xmlToDataFrame` and `rbind`ing until after the parsing. Another is to `readLines` in the RAW XML and then do all the other processing locally/after the reading (potentially in parallel).

Answer (score 0):

If parsing the XML into a tree is your pinchpoint (in xmlTreeParse) maybe use a streaming interface like [SAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) which will allow you to only process those elements that are useful for your application. I haven't used it, but the package `xml2` is built on top of libxml2 which provides a SAX ability.